# Ajax array response to form-control div

Tags: java, ajax, livesearch

Im trying to add/append my response from an AJAX request
[(here is the response)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9YH2.png) to a div with class list group. Would you advise me  how to do it?

I dont know how to add code here so Ill add photos instead.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9YH2.png). The link returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUjqo.png), and I need the `matching_full_name` part of each result.

I dont know what to look for to create the solution. I tried appending the `href`, but failed miserably.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSllk.png) is the expected result.

```
$('.form-control').keyup(function(event) {
    var input = $(this).val();
    console.log(input);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'json',
        data: {search: input},
        success: function(response) {
            // I dont know what to write here
```

> HTML HERE

```
<body>          
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a city..."
    <hr>

    <div class="list-group"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through result recieve from ajax response using `$.each` loop and use `+=` to append result to some variable and then use `.html` to show data under div.

**Demo Code** :

```js
var lis = ""; //declare 
$('.form-control').keyup(function(event) {
  $(".result").html(" "); //empty ul
  var input = $(this).val();
  //if input not empty
  if (input != "") {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/',
      type: 'GET',
      data: 'json',
      data: {
        search: input
      },
      success: function(response) {
        //loop through result
        $.each(response["_embedded"]["city:search-results"], function(index, element) {
          //append
          lis += "<li>" + element.matching_full_name + "</li>"

        });
        //add data under ul
        $(".result").html(lis);

      }

    });
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a city..." <hr>

  <div class="list-group">
    <ul class="result">
      <!--here result will come-->
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: This helped a lot, i have troubles understanding what  _embedded does, but im looking on it right now, however the code/list does not update when i type the full name of the city to only get city full names, thanks a lot tho ! that gave me the right direction

Comment: that url where you send search value gives you result or not ?

Comment: yeah it does, but it gives all the results, not the results for specific name

Comment: put url like this -> `url: 'https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/?search='+input` Its working in browser i.e :`https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/?search=america` <-type and see in browser.I don't know why that doesn't work here :) .